# Firefox ignoring CSS3 transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So I've been trying to get a transition working properly in firefox, This is what I have at the moment:

index.html:

```
<button type="button" id="pushButton">Push Me!</button>

<div id="loginBackground" class="login-background">
    <div id="loginBox" class="login-box-inactive">

    </div>
</div>
```

global_style.css:

```
.login-background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.login-box-inactive, .login-box-active {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.login-box-active {
    min-width: 350px;
    min-height: 350px;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, ease-in-out, 0.5s;
}
```

finally, login.js:

```
"use strict";

var pushButton = document.getElementById("pushButton");

var loginBackground = document.getElementById("loginBackground");
var loginBox        = document.getElementById("loginBox");

pushButton.onclick = function() {
    loginBackground.style.display = "flex";
    loginBox.className = "login-box-active";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
     if(event.target == loginBackground) {
         loginBackground.style.display = "none";
         loginBox.className = "login-box-inactive";
     }
}
```

AFAIK, pretty much every modern browser to date has standardised the transition tag so why is it that firefox is ignoring the transition tag entirely?

Thanks!

EDIT:

So I now have the following within my CSS file:

```
transition-property: all;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

Chrome plays well and displays this as should. Firefox still continues to ignore them. I even prefixed `-moz-` on them and it still ignored them.

EDIT 2:

I would like the following to happen once the button is pressed:

1) User presses `Press Me!` button.

2) `loginBackground` then overlays any content below (imagine the button is not the only content on page), rendering none of it clickable.

3) User will then have a choice of filling form out within `loginBox` or clicking a `closeButton` or `loginBackground`, both of which have the following outcome:

3.1) Upon user clicking either `closeButton` or `loginBackground` the `loginBox` and `loginBackground` disappears, leaving content underneath usable.

Comment: If that's the case then is it possible to have the `loginBackground` element be in front of the whole webpage and cover it without `position` needing to be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is both of these browsers handle the display property kind of differently. The execution of your transition depends on the display property of the loginBackground which is "display:none" initially. The box that is changing the dimension is a child of this division. Now, the interesting thing that is happening is:

Firefox is removing the child of the parent which has display:none set

Here's what firefox's mdn doc on display says:

[In addition to the many different display box types, the value none lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use none, all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tree.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

That's why when you are toggling display value on firefox the transition's don't occur since it's kind of removed and reinserted; essentially making it have no previous value to start of the transition from.

If you apply the "login-box-active" class with a slight delay, everything starts working as expected

```js
"use strict";

var pushButton = document.getElementById("pushButton");

var loginBackground = document.getElementById("loginBackground");
var loginBox        = document.getElementById("loginBox");

pushButton.onclick = function() {
    loginBackground.style.display = "flex";
    setTimeout(function() {
      loginBox.className = "login-box-active";
     }, 400)
   
    
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
     if(event.target == loginBackground) {
         loginBackground.style.display = "none";
         loginBox.className = "login-box-inactive";
     }
}
```

```css
.login-background {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.login-box-inactive, .login-box-active {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


.login-box-active {
    min-width: 350px;
    min-height: 350px; 
     transition: width 2s, height 2s, ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="pushButton">Push Me!</button>

<div id="loginBackground" class="login-background">
    <div id="loginBox" class="login-box-inactive">

    </div>
</div>
```

In the curious case of Chrome, it kind of does not remove the child of "display:none". That's why the transition works as usual on it.

Although, I would suggest to use simple opacity to achieve such effect instead of playing with display. Something, like this:

```js
"use strict";

var pushButton = document.getElementById("pushButton");

var loginBackground = document.getElementById("loginBackground");
var loginBox        = document.getElementById("loginBox");

pushButton.onclick = function() {
    loginBackground.style.opacity = "1";
    loginBox.className = "login-box-active";
   
    
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
     if(event.target == loginBackground) {
         loginBox.className = "login-box-inactive";
          loginBackground.style.opacity = "0";
     }
}
```

```css
.login-background {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: opacity 2s;
}


.login-box-inactive, .login-box-active {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transition: width 2s, height 2s, ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.login-box-active {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;  
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="pushButton">Push Me!</button>

<div id="loginBackground" class="login-background">
    <div id="loginBox" class="login-box-inactive">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the intended action I was after! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> transition: width 2s, height 2s, ease-in-out, 0.5s;
> ```

This line seems to be incorrect.
Try to remove last value and move timing function to a separate property.

Comment: That seems to entirely break everything